# Combining and Sorting by Geo Distance with Relevance Score

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to sort results according to relevance score and geo distance together. What is the best way to do so?

```
Data -1:
Job Title: Waitress (Boost:100)
Similar Jobs: Busboy (Boost:10)
Lat Lon: [45, 62]

Data-2:
Job Title: Busboy (Boost:100)
Similar Jobs: Waitress (Boost:10)
Lat Lon: [45, 64]
```

When I search for
`Waitress (in Job Title and Similar Jobs fields) - Geo Location: [45, 64] -  Sorting by Geo Location`

Despite the high score for Data-1, Data-2 is sorted first because it is closer to searched location just a lit bit.

I want to sort the results together with Score and geo location. If the difference between Geo location is not big, I want Data-1 to be sorted first.

Comment: Also, can I use _score inside sort script?

Answer (score -1):

The "sort" parameter accepts an array of fields or elements. If your priority of sorting data by relevance before sorting by distance, then put "_score" first then put geo-sorting schema, or else vice versa.